# List Received notifications in a Diffrent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

I have a Form sheet in which i have to display list of recently received ios Notifications, I have created from sheet. and i am receiving notifications too. How should i take all recived notification and the notified message in a separe view.

Comment: is form sheet and view are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like the following:

1. Store the Notifications (filter the ones you want) on the device
   storage (`NSUserDefaults`)
2. Create a new view in your app and read the data from the device
   storage (`NSUserDefaults`)

You can store almost anything in the device storage, string, custom object etc.

Comment: is it a correct way. I came across handling local notification in a differnt way. like calling  UILocal remote notifications and displaying it in a table view. Is there somethign like that ?

Comment: You will have to handle your notifications via the standard functions only, but to display them together in a single view, you'd need to store them. In case your requirement is not what has been suggested, please do tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the notifications in a shared instance class or data manager (singleton) class it's a good practice storing in manager class instead of NsuserDefaults